# Dictionary with Panda Dataframe as value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Here is below the output of the object dic when I print it:

```
{'Stock':             Price
date               
2018-11-23  150
2018-11-26  153}
```

By printing dic['Stock'] I end up with:

```
            Price
date               
2018-11-23  150
2018-11-26  153
```

The type of this object is `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`.

Then I tried to use the function $pandas.Series and I found out that this DataFrame contains only one column named Price.

Is there a simple way to extract the dates and prices and put them in different lists or a 2x2 matrix?

Thanks!

Comment: you may access the dates as `d['Stock'].index.values` and the prices as `d['Stock'].Price.values`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dic['Stock'].reset_index().values.tolist()
#[['2018-11-23', 150], ['2018-11-26', 153]]
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the dates, you want to look at your **index** of your dataframe.  Specifically, I would use the following function to extract just the dates:

(Assuming that your Data Frame is called `df`)

`dates = df.index.values`

This will save all the dates into a list that you can go ahead and use in any way that you would like!

---

Check out EXL skills for more help with coding in python!

https://exlskills.com/learn-en/courses/learn-python-essentials-for-data-science-intro_to_python/content